# can you access my database remotely if you've got my database login credentials

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access

If someone was to find out my database name, server, username and password, how easy is it for them to access my database?

My hosting is host gator.

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator disables remote logins to MySQL by default. To enable it you must go to your control panel and enable it and add a whitelist of permitted IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

They need the host name, a username and password and the port which is generaly 21.

So to access google's data base (FTP) is would be somthing like:
Host: google.com
Username: ?
Password: ?
Port: 21

So they can't access it unless then have all of the information.

Comment: That is if it is FTP, for MySQL the port would be different.